# ArrayList matrix

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`-s.
How can I initialize the field with given number of rows and number of columns?
I tried this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> field;

public Field(int rows, int cols) {
    field = new ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>(rows);
    for(ArrayList<E> t : field)
        t = new ArrayList<E>(cols);
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: do you know arraylist is dynamic? and do you know what dynamic means?

Comment: there is no need to initialize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this:

```
public class Field<E> {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<E>> field;

    public Field(int rows, int cols) {
        field = new ArrayList<ArrayList<E>>(rows);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            ArrayList<E> row  = new ArrayList<E>(cols);
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                row.add(null);
            }
            field.add(row);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field<String> field = new Field<String>(10, 10);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the size of a [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

The main reason to use a List is that its size can change.

With a List you can just do this:

```
// declare and initialize List of Lists

List<List<Foo>> listOfFooLists = new ArrayList<List<Foo>>();

// create a List from some method

List<Foo> someFooList = createListOfFoos();

// add the List to the List of Lists

listOfFooLists.add(someFooList);

// get the first Foo from the first list of Foos

Foo f = listOfFooLists.get(0).get(0);
```

Comment: this is a comment bro, not answer. remove it please.